# How can I not get the value -inf when dividing by zero?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting a annoying result when calculating the % difference between two columns in my dataframe.

Here's a sample of my data:

```
19044   109328.6627 4.74084555
0   53655.32937 inf
0   52591.95235 inf
0   56103.29265 inf
```

column 1 and 2 are numbers from my dataframe and column 3 is me generating % change. The problem, I assume, is when I divide by 0 I get inf. This impacts my calucations later.

This is my calculation:

```
TestResults['diff'] = ((abs(TestResults['B']).astype(float) - abs(TestResults['A']).astype(float)) / abs(TestResults['A']).astype(float))
```

I also had similar results when I tried this command also:

```
TestResults['diff'] = TestResults['B'].sub(df['A'].shift()).div(df['A']).fillna(0)
```

I assume I can do a df.column.replace to get rid of the inf value but I'd prefer not to generate it to begin with.

What can I do?

Comment: How about https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html instead?

Comment: @AKX I didn't even know that existed! I'll try it out right now. Thank you.

Comment: You can also add try/except...

Comment: @AKX I got a error when trying to cast it to a column(current df only has columns A, B..I'm trying to add a third one with the results of the difference) - TestResults['diff'] = TestResults.pct_change()  - 
KeyError: 'diff'

Comment: @zvi strange thing is, it doesn't give me a error. I do not know this occurred until a downstream process spits out a error because it's expecting only numerical values.

Comment: So you can write your own div function

Comment: @zvi Not sure how to do that, I can look that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In numpy you can set err behavior:

Division by zero can, however, be caught using seterr:

```py
np.seterr(divide='raise')
np.divide(1, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FloatingPointError: divide by zero encountered in divide
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html

Another option would be to write you own div function, for example:

```py
def safe_div(x,y):
    if y == 0:
        return 0
    return x / y
```

And in your code:

```py
TestResults['diff'] = safe_div(TestResults['B'].sub(df['A'].shift()),(df['A']).fillna(0))
```

Comment: it returns this error - ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()